# Map in SwiftUI produces `Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior` warning

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

When I drag my `Map` I am seeing this error in the debug window. I've seen it before, yet here I'm not entirely sure how to correct it.

```
Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

After considerable toying with it, and removing the `Passing of Views` per comment recommendations, the issue still persists. I created this view which makes the problem reproducible.

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    let pois: [POI]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(
            coordinateRegion: $region,
            annotationItems: pois,
            annotationContent: { location in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate, content: {
                    AnnotationView()
                })
            })
    }
    
    init(pois: [POI]) {
        self.pois = pois
        _region = State(initialValue: RegionCalculator.calculateRegion(from: pois))
    }
}

struct AnnotationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image("person.circle")
                .padding(2)
                .background {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                }
        }
    }
}

class RegionCalculator {
    static func calculateRegion(from pois: [POI]) -> MKCoordinateRegion {
        guard !pois.isEmpty else {
            return MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        }
        
        var totalLat = 0.0
        var totalLong = 0.0
        
        for poi in pois {
            totalLat += poi.coordinate.latitude
            totalLong += poi.coordinate.longitude
        }
        
        let avgLat = totalLat / Double(pois.count)
        let avgLong = totalLong / Double(pois.count)
        
        return MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: avgLat, longitude: avgLong), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    }
}
```

I discovered that the `MapAnnotation(...)` is the root cause of the problem, as the `AnnotationView()` is being redrawn everytime a the map is dragged. Simply having a `Map(coordinateRegion: $region)` proves this to be the cause.

```
annotationItems: pois,
            annotationContent: { location in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate, content: {
                    AnnotationView()
                })
            }
```

Here is the POI struct

```
struct POI: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    let lat: Double
    let long: Double
    let poiDetail: POIDetail
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }
}
```

Comment: Views shouldn’t be passed around like that. AnyView is highly discouraged. If you watch “Demystify SwiftUI” you’ll get greater insight into why.

Comment: First of all change it to `struct MapPageView<Map: View>: View {` and then you can declare `let map: Map` instead of `any View`  - that will solve some of your problems

Comment: @loremipsum unfortunately in my case regardless if I use AnyView or not, the issue still persists. I implemented the suggestion above, and I still get the same error thrown, which definitely indicates that I still have an State handling issue.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is impossible to help

Comment: The original comment is correct. You are attempting to pass a SwiftUI view as a parameter to another view. Don't.

Comment: @loremipsum the issue has been updated. I removed AnyView and also am no longer passing the view as a view constructor parameter. However I did discover that the issue is directly related to that MapAnnotation for the annotationContent.

Comment: Seems to be a known bug with an update to come that resolves it. Have you tried Xcode 15? You might be able to ignore it for a few months until RC is released if it is resolved there https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718697